# Meterse entre el pecho y la espalda -meaning

Tags: modismos

I recently came across the following phrase in a podcast by Español Automático: podcast no 217. Hablamos de Leonardo diCaprio.
The phrase is :

> Nos hemos **metido entre el pecho y la espalda** unas veintialgo películas.

I think "meterse entre el pecho y la espalda" can be used with food, as in stuffing oneself. How is it used?

In the context of movies is it the equivalent of the English, we binge-watched several movies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/pecho)

> entre pecho y espalda
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. En el estómago.

In English

> *between chest and back*
>
> 1. *Into the stomach*

As you pointed, usually this expression is used with food to remark the consumption of a great quantity ("stuffing oneself").

If you check the meaning of **[binge-watching](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binge-watching)** in the Wikipedia in Spanish, you'll find the term **atracón**
*Un maratón de series, **atracón** de series, y las expresiones inglesas binge-watching, binge-viewing o marathon-viewing, son términos que hacen referencia a la acción de ver varios capítulos de la misma serie de televisión de forma continua*

In [this term](https://dle.rae.es/atrac%C3%B3n?m=form) we can find the key of your question

> 1. m. Exceso en una actividad cualquiera. *Atracón de trabajar, de llorar.*
> 2. m. coloq. Acción y efecto de atracar (‖ comer y beber con exceso).

Being the main use of atracón an excess on eating and drinking (2), the term can be used with an excess on any activity (1).

Summarizing

> Nos hemos metido **entre el pecho y la espalda** unas veintialgo películas.
> =
> Nos hemos dado un **atracón** de unas veintialgo películas
> = EN
> *We have watched twentysomething movies in a row*
> =
> *We have **binge-watched** twentysomething movies*

Last but not least, the expression gathered in the DLE does not show the articles present in your sentence, el and la, as Charlie has pointed in the comments. I agree with him, the most common form is entre pecho y espalda, with no articles.

Comment: Quite an old expression, I've always seen it without the articles: "entre pecho y espalda". In fact, it is already present in that form in the dictionary by Covarrubias, published in 1611: "Entre pecho y espalda, termino de los que comen valientemente." It also appears in the Quixote by Avellaneda, published in 1614: "El qual tomó Sancho, y una a una [...] se las metió entre pecho y espalda."

Comment: I've always seen it without the articles too. You should include those references in an answer. Always great to know old references to words and expressions. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In some occasions, it can be interpreted with food (*eat a lot*), but in other circumstances, it can mean the excess of something

So, the example you provided

> Nos hemos metido entre el pecho y la espalda unas veintialgo películas

Means that "twenty-something" movies have been seen, that is, at least twenty have been seen and there may be a possibility that the number is higher.

Depending on the circumstance, the meaning may vary

> Se metió entre pecho y espalda tres copazos y se puso al volante

In this case, it mean drink

Comment: Yes, you are all correct. I checked the original transcript of the podcast and the definite articles are not present in the expression. Just "entre pecho y espalda"